# How can I add a custom command to Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

There's an external command I'm using constantly - basically launching a batch file. I'd like to put a toolbar button (and possibly keyboard shortcut) for this into the IDE. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Here is a blog post I wrote on that. It's integrating Subversion: http://gbdarren.blogspot.com/2014/07/adding-tortoisesvn-commands-to-visual.html

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First, add an item to your Tools menu by choosing Tools, External Tools, and filling out the dialog, like this:

[image]

Then bring up Tools Customize, click the Keyboard button at the bottom, and find the appropriate external tool number:

[image: bind to a key]

Comment: You lost me at "and find the appropriate external tool number" What does this mean, and how do we know which one is appropriate?

Comment: count them - in my screenshot Create GUID is 1, and so on until Spy++ is 5 and the new command is 6

Comment: @KateGregory Answer updated, and now is correct. we can delete comments.

Comment: since the screenshot doesn't include the bound command, you made it worse, not better @T.Todua

Comment: @KateGregory How i made it worse, i cant understand what you say. I havent removed anything existing from previous screenshot, what could be valuable. Could you modify & specify what you mean?

Answer (score 4):

All the configured external commands in VS are available to add to a Toolbar or Menu through the Tools>Customize menu as "External Command ##".  You just need to know which number corresponds to the particular command you've configured.  I believe it is in order of entry in the external commands list.

Similarly, you can find those names in the commands list in Options>Environment>Keyboard and assign a shortcut to your command that way.

Comment: +1 -- but How do I configure what these external commands are?

Comment: Yes, I think you're missing some steps here.

Comment: Note they can be added to context menus as well: 
1. Tools>Customize->Commands->Context menu 
2. Choose the context menu you want 
3. Click "Add Command" 
4. The external commands will appear in the "Tools" category as "External Command X"